# setCredentials is not a function in googleapis.auth.OAuth2

Tags: node.js, google-api-nodejs-client

I was using the "googleapis" node module. Since couple of days I started getting below error :

> this.oauth2Client.setCredentials is not a function ..

Code :

```
var google = require('googleapis');
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
this.oauth2Client = new OAuth2(endpointdetails.gss_endpoint.targetBinding[0].value, endpointdetails.gss_endpoint.targetBinding[1].value);
this.oauth2Client.setCredentials({
    access_token: endpointdetails.gss_endpoint.targetBinding[2].value,
    refresh_token: endpointdetails.gss_endpoint.targetBinding[3].value,
    expiry_date: true
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use:

```
oauth2Client.credentials = tokens;
```

in place of

```
oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
```

https://github.com/google/google-api-nodejs-client/issues/869#issuecomment-346533545